# How to remove wood water stain on bathroom laminate countertop?

Tags: bathroom, water, laminate, stain-removal

[image]This 3 inch stain has been here before we moved in. It appears the that something has worn away the laminate off and is exposing the particle board. Imagine a rock sediment exposure image.

How do I repair or remove this stain, without replacing the entire countertop?

Comment: How about a picture.

Comment: We cannot see what you see.

Comment: we are imagining, but it is not working

Comment: I'm sorry I'm new and struggling with the picture upload.

Comment: Laminate takes a lot of wearing to wear away, and the edges of the wearing would not be so defined. Acid burn, maybe? Do you feel an actual depression there, as in do your fingers drop into the damaged area a millimeter or 1/16th inch-ish?

Comment: Sanding/painting will probably cover it, but it will look like a patch repair.  If you want to hide it, make a design statement and place something in it.  A round/square flat piece you could use to place hot pots on, a nice looking coaster.

Comment: I'm on mobile and I don't know how to reply to a specific person. There is no dent or depression, it is flat but I can feel the edge slightly

Answer (score 0):

Standard procedure would be to sand then sand some more till it is perfectly smooth.

Pain will not cover and irregularity but will cover the stain.

Now go to paint store and tell them what you want to do so they give you the right paint and tools.

Painting might not work to cover the defect. Research products like  Formica and Wilsonart

Comment: I added the pic! Sorry it took me awhile - noob at this. Thank you in advance and my sincerest apologies for the trouble

Comment: That would require some wood filler before sanding and painting